How to flatten Pandas Dataframe column levels?
I used .agg() in Pandas and got nested columns.
data.groupby(["plant_id", "plant_name", "scientific_name"],
             as_index=False).agg(["mean", "std", "min", "max"])

How to flatten the column labels/levels? The code below didn't work.
flat_cols = ['plant_id', 'plant_name', 'scientific_name'] + [
             param+"_"+metric for metric in ["mean", "std", "min", "max"]
             for param in ['soil_moisture', 'temperature']]

data.columns = flat_cols


Welcome to SO. Please read about how to ask a question. One of the key ingredients in a question is providing sample data to reproduce the errors or test potential solutions. It will help yuo get the answers you are looking for.

Here is an example on how to do this. I created a simple example of a dataframe that matches your columns:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'plant_id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'plant_name': ['Sunflower', 'Sunflower', 'Rose', 'Rose'],
    'scientific_name': ['Helianthus', 'Helianthus', 'Rosa', 'Rosa'],
    'soil_moisture': [20, 30, 40, 50],
    'temperature': [70, 75, 80, 85]
})

grouped = data.groupby(["plant_id", "plant_name", "scientific_name"], as_index=False).agg({
    'soil_moisture': ['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'],
    'temperature': ['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']
})

grouped.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() if type(col) is tuple else col for col in grouped.columns.values]

print(grouped)

which gives
   plant_id_ plant_name_ scientific_name_  soil_moisture_mean  \
0          1   Sunflower       Helianthus                25.0   
1          2        Rose             Rosa                45.0   

   soil_moisture_std  soil_moisture_min  soil_moisture_max  temperature_mean  \
0           7.071068                 20                 30              72.5   
1           7.071068                 40                 50              82.5   

   temperature_std  temperature_min  temperature_max  
0         3.535534               70               75  
1         3.535534               80               85  

Aternatively, as pointed out in the commment:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'plant_id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'plant_name': ['Sunflower', 'Sunflower', 'Rose', 'Rose'],
    'scientific_name': ['Helianthus', 'Helianthus', 'Rosa', 'Rosa'],
    'soil_moisture': [20, 30, 40, 50],
    'temperature': [70, 75, 80, 85]
})

grouped = data.groupby(["plant_id", "plant_name", "scientific_name"]).agg({
    'soil_moisture': ['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max'],
    'temperature': ['mean', 'std', 'min', 'max']
}).reset_index()

grouped.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() if type(col) is tuple else col for col in grouped.columns.values]

print(grouped)


It's perhaps simpler to remove the as_index=False from the groupby, then you don't need the test in the comprehension and you can just reset_index after renaming the columns.

@Nick Well noted. I edited my answer with this as an alternative.

You misinterpreted me, you don't do the reset_index until after assigning the columns, so you do grouped.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in grouped.columns] and then grouped = grouped.reset_index()

I have later found a way using droplevel():
data = data.groupby(["plant_id", "plant_name", "scientific_name"], as_index=False
                    ).agg(["mean", "std", "min", "max"]
                          ).droplevel(1, axis=1)

data.columns = ['plant_id', 'plant_name', 'scientific_name'] + \ 
               [param+"_"+metric
                for param in ['soil_moisture', 'temperature']
                for metric in ["mean", "std", "min", "max"]]

